# Show all level section numbering in text, but not in ToC?

Tags: titlesec, titletoc

I want section numbering in ToC to appear as

```
\renewcommand\thesection{\Roman{section}}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\alph{subsection}}
\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{\arabic{subsubsection}}
```

but in text the full numbering should be seen:

```
\renewcommand\thesection{\Roman{section}}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\Roman{section}.\alph{subsection}}
\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{\Roman{section}.\alph{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}}
```

Is it possible with titlesec/titletoc?

Comment: Ooh, i think this will be a little bit confusing for the reader, depending how long the document (and levelled) it is.

Comment: @Johannes_B: but citing all the subnumbers in ToC is ugly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enclose the parts you don't want in the TOC in a macro that's usually defined just to print its contents, but when doing the note in the `.aux` file for the TOC entry it's redefined to gobble its contents.

The macro responsible for the annotation is `\addtocontents` that already does something like this, by redefining `\label`, `\index` and `\glossary` to gobble their arguments; so we just need to add another macro to the list.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{Blue}{HTML}{2E3192}

% heading styles:
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\color{teal}\large\sffamily}
  {\thetitle.\hspace{0.5cm}}
  {0cm}
  {}

\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\color{violet}\bfseries}
  {\hspace{0.75cm}\thetitle.\hspace{0.3cm}}
  {0cm}
  {}

\titleformat{\subsubsection}
  {\color{olive}\itshape}
  {\hspace{1.3cm}\thetitle.\hspace{0.3cm}}
  {0cm}
  {}

% ToC styles:
\usepackage[dotinlabels]{titletoc}
\contentsmargin{2.55em} % space for a page number

\titlecontents{section}
    [3.8em] % 1.5em + 2.3em
    {\vspace{0.3cm}\sffamily\bfseries\large}
    {\contentslabel{2.3em}}
    {\hspace*{-2.3em}}
    {\normalsize\normalfont\rmfamily\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}
    [\vspace{0.1cm}]

\titlecontents{subsection}
    [5.2em] % 3.8em + 1.3em
    {\vspace{0.1cm}}
    {\contentslabel{1.4em}}
    {\hspace*{-1.4em}}
    {\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}
    []

\titlecontents{subsubsection}
    [6.5em] % 5.2em + 1.3em
    {\vspace{0.1cm}}
    {\contentslabel{1.3em}}
    {\hspace*{-1.3em}}
    {\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}
    []

\makeatletter
\let\perhapsprint\@firstofone
\patchcmd{\addtocontents}
  {\glossary\@gobble}
  {\glossary\@gobble\let\perhapsprint\@gobble}
  {}{}
%\newcommand{\perhapsprint}[1]{\ifprintprefix#1\fi}
%\newif\ifprintprefix
\renewcommand\thesection{\Roman{section}}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{%
  \perhapsprint{\Roman{section}.}%
  \alph{subsection}%
}
\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{%
  \perhapsprint{\Roman{section}.\alph{subsection}.}%
  \arabic{subsubsection}%
}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{A section}\label{1}

References: \ref{1}, \ref{2}, \ref{3}, \ref{4}.

\lipsum[1]
\subsection{A subsection}\label{2}
\lipsum[2-4]
\subsection{Another subsection}\label{3}
\lipsum[5]
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}\label{4}
\lipsum[6]
\subsection{A subsection}\lipsum[7-8]
\subsection{Another subsection}\lipsum[9-10]
\section{Another section}\lipsum[1-2]
\subsection{A subsection}\lipsum[3-4]
\subsection{Another subsection}\lipsum[5-6]
\subsection{A subsection}\lipsum[7-8]
\subsection{Another subsection}\lipsum[9-10]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Oh, I solved it. Re-defining section formats in the `titleformat` works:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{Blue}{HTML}{2E3192}

% heading styles:
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\color{teal}\large\sffamily}
  {\thetitle.\hspace{0.5cm}}
  {0cm}
  {}

\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\color{violet}\bfseries}
  {\renewcommand\thesubsection{\Roman{section}.\alph{subsection}}\hspace{0.75cm}\thetitle.\hspace{0.3cm}}
  {0cm}
  {}

\titleformat{\subsubsection}
  {\color{olive}\itshape}
  {\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{\Roman{section}.\alph{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}}\hspace{1.3cm}\thetitle.\hspace{0.3cm}}
  {0cm}
  {}

% ToC styles:
\usepackage[dotinlabels]{titletoc}
\contentsmargin{2.55em} % space for a page number

\titlecontents{section}
    [3.8em] % 1.5em + 2.3em
    {\vspace{0.3cm}\sffamily\bfseries\large}
    {\contentslabel{2.3em}}
    {\hspace*{-2.3em}}
    {\normalsize\normalfont\rmfamily\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}
    [\vspace{0.1cm}]

\titlecontents{subsection}
    [5.2em] % 3.8em + 1.3em
    {\vspace{0.1cm}}
    {\contentslabel{1.4em}}
    {\hspace*{-1.4em}}
    {\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}
    []

\titlecontents{subsubsection}
    [6.5em] % 5.2em + 1.3em
    {\vspace{0.1cm}}
    {\contentslabel{1.3em}}
    {\hspace*{-1.3em}}
    {\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}
    []

\renewcommand\thesection{\Roman{section}}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\alph{subsection}}
\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{\arabic{subsubsection}}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{A section}\lipsum[1]
\subsection{A subsection}\lipsum[2-4]
\subsection{Another subsection}\lipsum[5-6]
\subsection{A subsection}\lipsum[7-8]
\subsection{Another subsection}\lipsum[9-10]
\section{Another section}\lipsum[1-2]
\subsection{A subsection}\lipsum[3-4]
\subsection{Another subsection}\lipsum[5-6]
\subsection{A subsection}\lipsum[7-8]
\subsection{Another subsection}\lipsum[9-10]
\end{document}
```

gives:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for sharing, can you extend the document to make it compilable and show an example? It is easier for other help seekers that way.

Comment: Uh, no! This is not the way to do it!